# Using LOTUS to prove the statement

Tags: probability, expectation

**Question:** Use LOTUS to show that for X ~ Pois(λ) and any function g(.), E(Xg(X)) = λE(g(X+1)).

**The steps I have taken are shown below**

It is given that mean is E(X)=λ

The Law of Unconscious Statistician is

$$E(g(X))=\sum_{x} g(x)f_X(x)$$
Then,

$$E(Xg(X))=\sum_{x} Xg(x)f_X(x)$$
$$=E(X)E(g(x)f_X(x))$$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179105/a-property-of-poisson-distribution),but the answer below is useful!

Comment: I want it in the form of a story proof, which this doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Answer by angryavian is sufficient,i think!

Answer (score 5):

The second step is not correct; you cannot split a sum like that into two expectations.

\begin{align}
E[X g(X)]
&= \sum_{x=0}^\infty x g(x) f_X(x)
\\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty x g(x) f_X(x) & \text{addend is zero when $x=0$}
\\
&= \sum_{x=1}^\infty x g(x) e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}
& \text{plug in PMF of Poisson distr.}
\\
&= \lambda\sum_{x=1}^\infty g(x) e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}
& \text{rearrange terms}
\\
&= \lambda \sum_{x=0}^\infty g(x+1) e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}.
& \text{shift indexing}
\end{align}

Comment: From second step to 3rd step you are using just the PMF of Poisson r.v!